# vagrant homestead directory missing

Tags: laravel, vagrant, laravel-5, homestead, vagrant-windows

when I run command **ls** it doesn't show any file.

[image]

My homestead.yaml file:

[image]

which directory should i look in to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's seems to be some issues with homestead lately for windows folk.

to make sure you can access your files in the VM just add the following in your `Vagrantfile`

```
config.vm.synced_folder "C:/Users/<User>/projects", "/home/vagrant/Code"
```

Comment: can you make sure files are available on VM under `/home/vagrant/Code` in your yaml file you have my_site.app not ao.dev

Comment: yes they are available ,and how come i have my_site.app?

Comment: oops sorry I was reading it from the answer below not your question ! did you change your host file ? can you access from IP ?

Comment: I've this in hosts file: 127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.10.10   homestead.app
192.168.10.10   ao.dev

Comment: can you access the site from the VM ?

Comment: dont know how to do that

Comment: are you talking about virtualbox,yes it says failed to open session for virtual machine.......

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118939/discussion-between-yash-chaudhary-and-frederic-henri).

Answer (score 0):

Try to provision the Vagrant VM

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

Answer (score -1):

I paste my Homestead.yaml file. You are in Windows, so try to put your complete local folder (C:\Users\my_user\development in my machine) and provision the machine another time

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
 - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
 - map: C:\Users\my_user\development
 to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
 - map: my_site.app
 to: /home/vagrant/Code/web/my_site/public
databases:
 - my_database
```